# PHP str_replace doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, string, str-replace

I'm trying to use str_replace to correct a filepath as shown below:

```
$a="F:\xampp\htdocs\yii\get_smart\Music\mix\English\1636464449";  
$a=str_replace('\\','/', $a);  
echo $a;
```

returns:

```
F:
mpp/htdocs/yii/get_smart/Music/mix/Englishs6464449
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

My PHP version is 5.3.8

Comment: What is your expected/desired result?

Answer (score 11):

Use single quote for define $a

```
$a='F:\xampp\htdocs\yii\get_smart\Music\mix\English\1636464449';
```

the problem is not `str_replace` but the string defined within double quotes. The backslashes escape the `x` and other character after it.

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because your string is in double quotes, so the `\x` is being parsed as a character.

Actually, it's trying to read `\xam` as a character.  Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php

Put your string in single quotes (or escape the slash before the `x`).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the first string has some escaped sequences.  For example \xam has a meaning in php.  It looks like \16 might also mean something.  You should echo $a before you do the str_replace and see what you get.